# Temporary WP8/WinRT-Store-Licence and deployed app

Tags: deployment, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

If I wan't to code a WindowsPhone8-/WinRT-App I recieve a temporary licence. If I debug my app it will be installed localy or on the remote device (that I added to the debuger).

My question is, can I use the installed app after the licence key expires? Or do I need to connect my tablet again to the pc to "rebuild" the app with the new key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the license expires you can't launch your app again and you will need to rebuilt it after extending your license.

You can extend the 30 days to 90 days with a Windows Store account or create a business account.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows Phone:**

There is no limit for the Windows Phone emulator (but then again all apps are wiped when you restart the emulator).

For a Windows Phone developer device which you have registered there is an expiry date you can check on [the developer portal](http://dev.windowsphone.com).

It's under Dashboard>>Account>>Phones.

This is typically one year from the date of unlocking your developer phone. After the expiry date the apps will no longer run and you will need to re-unlock your phone.